# Google Geocode OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: php, curl, google-geocoder, geocode

I've been getting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error response trying to retrieve an address' geo coordinates using the link below via server-side script:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&key=

API key is from an account which has enabled billing as well as its restrictions removed.

Would like to know what else I'm missing?

There's another API Key used via JS which works flawlessly under the same account.

Answer (score 0):

This is not error. You used over limit of request to query coordinate of your address.

I also faced same issue.

For me i was not add api key.

I got result from this url:[GMap URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?key=%22.GMAP_KEY.%22&origins=%22tolatitude,tolongitude%22&destinations=%22fromlatitude,fromlongitude%22&mode=driving&language=pl-PL)

For you, add **distancematrix** in url

It may be work for you.

Comment: There's a total of 7 requests since its inception and it hasn't been a day. Each request thrown after several minutes from the last.

Comment: sorry, I'm actually trying to retrieve the coordinates based on the given address. limit hasn't been reached yet on both api keys (7/2500?).